# How to change the Type-Reference passed in Jackson's readvalue dynamically?

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have two types of TypeReferences that will be passed in the jackson's readValue method.

```
1. Foo<AbstractResponse>
2. Foo <String>
```

How do i make the jackson readValue to work when either of these two references are passed

Since I'm dealing with Http calls, I tried sending custom error codes  and based on it changing the Type-reference being passed in the readValue method, which works. But I'm looking for a more efficient solution that this.

To make this work, i can either use this:

```
mapper.readValue(jsonParser, new TypeReference<Foo<AbstractResponse>(){})
```

or this

```
mapper.readValue(jsonParser, new TypeReference<Foo<String>(){})
```

But this is what is expected:

```
mapper.readValue(jsonParser, new new TypeReference<Foo<T>>() {})
```

Comment: What is `Foo<T>` ?

Comment: Foo is a generic Class which takes in either a class extended by AbstractResponse or a String

Comment: could you post the code please?

Comment: Have updated the question. Please check

Comment: could you post the code of `Foo`? please?

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectMapper`'s  method readValue is a generic method. Generics are resolved at compile time so you can't do this dynamically.

Suppose you have following method:

```
Foo<T> <T> bar(parser, TypeReference<Foo<T>> reference) {
   ...
   return mapper.readValue(jsonParser, reference);
}
```

You can't call it like this:

```
TypeReference<Foo<T>> reference;
switch (value) {
     case "X":
          reference = new TypeReference<Foo<AbstractResponse>(){};
          break;
     case "Y":
          reference = new TypeReference<Foo<String>(){};
          break;
 }
 bar(parser, reference);
```

But you can do following:

```
switch (value) {
     case "X":
          bar(parser, new TypeReference<Foo<AbstractResponse>(){});
          break;
     case "Y":
          bar(parser, new TypeReference<Foo<String>(){});
          break;
 }
```